# Unison on OS X -- Cannot connect

Tags: macos, unison

I am trying to use Unison on command line.

I have installed the command line tool, but running unison brings the GUI up. When I enter the password, the GUI stays at "connecting..." dialog and it spits out the exception:

```
"Exception raised during posting of notification.  Ignored.  exception: 'Unix error(Bad file descriptor,write,)'  invoked observer method: '*** -[MyController controlTextDidEndEditing:]'  observer: 0x257190  notification name: 'NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification'"
```

Any idea to resolve this issue, and run unison on command line? The connection works the other way around, from my Linux to my Mac.

.

Answer (score 1):

You could try having [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) build a truly text-only version instead of the GUI-version's “command line tool”. The appearance of NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification certainly seems to indicate that some GUI code is still being used by the “command line tool” it produced.

Answer (score 1):

Add "-ui text" to your command line.